# how i can make svnlook tree view just 2 level?

Tags: linux, svn, solaris, repository

how i can make `svnlook tree` view just 2 level ?

Comment: what do you mean by second level ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you want an option like `-L` of `tree` command? It seems that `svnlook tree` doesn't has any option like this:

```
# svnlook help tree
tree: usage: svnlook tree REPOS_PATH [PATH_IN_REPOS]

Print the tree, starting at PATH_IN_REPOS (if supplied, at the root
of the tree otherwise), optionally showing node revision ids.

Valid options:
  -r [--revision] ARG      : specify revision number ARG
  -t [--transaction] ARG   : specify transaction name ARG
  -N [--non-recursive]     : operate on single directory only
  --show-ids               : show node revision ids for each path
  --full-paths             : show full paths instead of indenting them
```